# Tableview row selection through delegate is selecting multiple rows instead of one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So when I hit a button on the custom cell it should deselect and select the image(change images representing checked and unchecked). But if I have a longer table view, I noticed that every fifth cell of the table view get selected or deselected. For example if I hit the button on the second cell, my seventh and 12th cell also get selected/deselected. I am guessing it is something to do with the dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier but not sure how to fix it.
So I have a custom cell class(called CounterOfferAddGameViewCell) with a protocol with one required method. The .h file

```
@class CounterOfferAddGameViewCell;
@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)tableViewCell:(CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *)cell didFireAddGameButtonForSender:(id)sender;
@end
....
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addGameButton;
- (IBAction)addGameButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CellDelegate>delegate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger cellIndex;
```

and the implementation:

```
@implementation CounterOfferAddGameViewCell
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (IBAction)addGameButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self didFireAddGameButtonForSender:sender];
}
@end
```

This is my code in the table view:

```
-(void)tableViewCell:(CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *)cell didFireAddGameButtonForSender:(id)sender
{
    if([[selectedGames objectAtIndex:cell.cellIndex] boolValue]){
        [cell.addGameButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButtonUnselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [selectedGames replaceObjectAtIndex:cell.cellIndex withObject:@NO];
    }
    else{
    [cell.addGameButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButtonIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [selectedGames replaceObjectAtIndex:cell.cellIndex withObject:@YES];
    }

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CounterOfferAddGameViewCell";

    CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *thisCell = (CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"%i",thisCell.cellIndex);
    if (thisCell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CounterOfferAddGameViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        thisCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    thisCell.delegate = self;
    thisCell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;
...
```

selectedGames is just an array with booleans:

```
for(int i=0;i<[gameCoreModelArray count];i++){
    [selectedGames insertObject:@NO atIndex:i];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are reusing a cell that has been selected previously without resetting its state back to unselected. You should be able to fix this in the code of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method by calling `setSelected:NO` and removing the image from `addGameButton`:

```
CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *thisCell = (CounterOfferAddGameViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

NSLog(@"%i",thisCell.cellIndex);
if (thisCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CounterOfferAddGameViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    thisCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
thisCell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;
if([[selectedGames objectAtIndex:thisCell.cellIndex] boolValue]){
    [thisCell.addGameButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButtonIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [thisCell.addGameButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButtonUnselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Well thank you. Even though your code will set every cell as unchecked (scenario when I check, then scroll down and then scroll up, the cell will get unchecked) your comment was right; I was reusing a checked cell. So all I did was check for selectedGames index when I create the cell and got the state. Thank you anyhow. I can't vote up as I do not have sufficient reputation, and can't mark as correct because the code creates another bug.:/

Comment: @Objectif You're right, the state is stored in `selectedGames`, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` needs to pay attention to the current state.